# Programmatic analysis of geometric shapes

Tags: java, algorithm, math, geometry

I’m trying to work out a math / geometry problem in a Java project I’m working.

Here is the scenario:

There are two sets of blocks, each with a different number of blocks and different dimensions. In this example Set A has 5 blocks, each is 20x20 pixels; Set B has 6 blocks, and each is 25x50 pixels:

[image: 5 blocks of 20x20]

I’m trying to come up with a way to mathematically or logically determine how those sets would line up to maximize the contact between them. If you were to line these set up end-to-end it would look like this:

[image: Four of the 25x25 blocks touch the 5 20x20 blocks]

In this image, 4 of the blocks in set B are in contact with the blocks in set A. However, if you shift set A to the right a bit, you can get 5 of the blocks in set B to touch:

[image]

The problem is that the formula / algorithm / logic needs to be flexible enough to handle different combinations. In this example, set C has only 3 blocks, and each block is 40x40:

[image: All 5 25x25 blocks touch the 40x40 blocks]

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm....the images aren't uploading...

Comment: Define "maximize the contact". Though I do believe the question to be too broad for SO.

Comment: #RealSkeptic - do the images make it clearer?

Comment: I'm afraid that you need to write more about the problem. Currently it seems that there is no problem - you have 2 rectangles and need to determine which side is longer  than the other...

Comment: Do the 2 classes of blocks have to stay in contact, or can they separate?

Comment: Are the blocks from a given set always the same size?

Comment: @pkalinow - The question isn't which set is larger. There are 5 20x25 blocks in the top set, and 6 25x50 blocks in the bottom. If you line them up in one way, for of the 25x50 blocks will be in contact with the 20x20 blocks. However if you shift their alignment slightly you can get 5 of the 25x50 blocks to touch the 20x20 blocks.

Comment: @eigenchris - no, they are not always going to be the same size.

Comment: @Bathsheba - They do need to stay in contact.

Comment: Must the blocks remain in the same order within the set, or are they required to reorder themselves to achieve greatest contact?

Comment: @fd - I added some more detail to the question, is that clearer?

Comment: Not really. It doesn't help that in your examples the blocks in each set are the same dimensions, which means the ordering is not important anyway. But imagine you had one set [10x10,20x10,30x10], then the question is: does the algorithm only consider them in this order, or should it deal with all distinct combinations (or permutations, if necessary) of ordering?

Comment: They are supposed to be the same dimensions. Set A: [20x20, 20x20, 20x20, 20x20, 20x20] and Set B: [25x50, 25X50, 25x50, 25x50, 25X50, 25x50], so the order of individual blocks in either set doesn't matter.

Comment: @rearden: You told eigenchris that the blocks from a given set are *not* always going to be the same size, but then you said that they *are* all the same size.  Which is it?

Comment: Also it's very unclear what arrangements are possible.  E.g. is it permitted to space the blocks in one or both sets out?  If so, you can get a lot more pairs of blocks from different sets in contact, by spacing out the narrower blocks.

Comment: Also you still haven't described what exactly you are trying to maximise.  Is it the number of pairs of blocks, having one block from A and one block from B, that have any boundary points in common?  Or is it the number of blocks that are touching at least one block in the other set?  Either way, is just an overlapping corner enough?  Potentially an interesting question, but still very unclear so -1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Center the two sets of blocks and shift one of them by a small amount.

Answer (score 1):

Check the difference in total length between the two sets of blocks.

- If the difference is less than the length of the smaller block, then just align the two sets of blocks on one edge; they all have contact with each other, so call it good.
- Otherwise, move the smaller set of blocks sideways by *almost* the length of one member of the other set (i.e., length of larger block minus some tiny number), to maximize contact.

It will look a bit like this (where top blocks are width 5, and bottom blocks are width 3):

```
111112222233333444445555566666
--->111222333444555
```

If you're aiming for the simpler answer of "how many blocks are in contact?", then the computation is simpler. The shorter set of blocks always has contact with the longer set of blocks. The longer set of blocks is in contact with this many blocks in the shorter set if the edges are exactly aligned:

(length of shorter set of blocks) / (length of a single member of longer block)

Add one if that's both less than the number of longer blocks, and if that fraction isn't an integer (to account for a tiny shift like I described earlier). Then round up.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to come up with a good algorithm for this without understanding what the program is actually trying to *do* ... but ok, you want to 'maximise' the contact between two **lists** of blocks (or are they really sets?).

One thing that occurs to me here is that the best alignment will have at least one of the separators between blocks aligned. So you could just keep the longer list fixed, and shift the shorter one along, stepping by separator alignment.

Comment: The code is simulating physical objects, so each "set" of blocks (as displayed above) is an array of object that have a length and width property. The objects in each array need to interact with each other as if they were physically touching; I'm trying to maximize the interaction so that as many objects are involved as possible.

Comment: Ok, the *collection* of blocks we could call a 'train'. I think you are asking to maximise the size of the graph formed by making a vertex for each block, and an edge for each contact. The graph made by two trains is a bipartite graph and you want one with as many edges as possible.

Comment: Ok, so thinking about it a bit more, for two trains with identical sized blocks, you get a forest (set of disconnected graphs) when the boundaries are completely aligned. Otherwise you get a zig-zag graph. When one train is larger than the other, your ziz-zag can turn into a tree.

Answer (score 0):

Let a_total and b_total be the total widths of the collections of blocks. Let a_single and b_single be the width of one of the blocks. We can assume a_total <= b_total (otherwise swap).

If the rows of blocks are aligned at their left edges, A is in contact with ceiling(a_total/b_single) blocks from B. That number can be increased by at most one by shifting the starting point of A to the right. The number is at most one because the situation is periodic for large B (imagine an infinitely long B, for example): shifting A by exactly b_single results in a configuration exactly the same as the starting configuration, so another B block has been added to the end.

The trick now is to see whether we can add a B block to the end by shifting the A collection, while not removing the B block at the beginning.

We can add a B block at the end only if B is long enough; the exact condition is a_total <= b_total - b_single.

We can avoid removing a B block from the beginning if we can shift the A collection by less than b_single in order for the right edge of the A collection to pass a B block boundary, in other words if and only if ceiling(a_total/b_single)*b_single - a_total < b_single, i.e., ceiling(a_total/b_single) < (a_total + b_single)/b_single, i.e., ceiling(a_total/b_single) < a_total/b_single + 1. The latter inequality is always true.

In summary, the number of blocks in contact is maximized at ceiling(a_total/b_total) + 1 if a_total <= b_total - b_single, and ceiling(a_total/b_total) otherwise (assuming, of course, that a_total <= b_total).

There is one further issue you need to consider: the above analysis holds when you can adjust the relative positions of the blocks by any real number. If you are restricted to one pixel adjustments, then you may get into further special cases if b_single = 1, for example.